# How to get pairwise iterator with last element as being the first

Tags: python, iterator, python-itertools

I am using the following function `pairwise` to get the iteration of ordered pairs. For example, if the iterable is a list `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` then I want to get `(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 1)`. If I use the following function

```
from itertools import tee, zip_longest
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip_longest(a, b)
```

then it returns `(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, None)`.

I am using `dataloader` in my code as iterable, so I want to pass only `iterable` as input to the function `pairwise` and I don't want to pass extra inputs.

How do I get the first element as the last element in the last item as mentioned above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`zip_longest` has `fillvalue` parameter

```
return zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=iterable[0])
```

or as suggested in the comments use the returned value of the `next(b, None)` in `fillvalue`

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    return zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=next(b, None))
```

Output

```
print(list(pairwise(lst))) # [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 1)]
```

You can also do it without converting the list to iterators

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    return zip_longest(iterable, iterable[1:], fillvalue=iterable[0])
```

Comment: Or `fillvalue=next(b, None)` :)

Comment: @Adam.Er8 this will give wrong output

Comment: Instead of the bare call to `next` in the middle of the function, of course.

Comment: Would it be nicer to def this as ```my_pairwise()``` or  *circular_pairwise* to avoid overshadow the standard lib's same function?  (if others use it) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply "append" the first element of the iterable to the iterable first.

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    first = next(iterable)
    new_iterable = chain([first], iterable, [first])

    a, b = tee(new_iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip_longest(a, b)
```